# where are Jinja2 variables and files located and how do i find them?

Tags: python, django, jinja2

noob here, so please bear with me.
My question is where is the web_include_css file and where is the link or abs_url variable? How do i find them?

```
{%- for link in web_include_css %}
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ link|abs_url }}">
{%- endfor -%}
```

Answer (score 0):

`web_include_css` is a variable passed down from server see the corresponding view function. Also `abs_url` is a template tag please see the templates tag folder for more info...

Comment: where would that view function be?

Comment: I don&#39;t know you tell me, you are the one there. I don&#39;t know about your project structure.